# Do element-wise monotonic functions preserve positive semi-definiteness?

Tags: linear-algebra

More precisely, given a PSD matrix $A$, and element-wise monotonic function $f$, (where element-wise is defined as $f(A)_{ij}=f(A_{ij}$) ), is $f(A)$ also PSD?

Intuitively this seems to be the case, at least for monotonic increasing functions.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix 
$$
A=\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 1& 2}
$$
is positive semidefinite with two positive eigenvalues. However,

$$
B=\pmatrix{-1 & -1 \\ -1 & 0}
$$
is not positive semidefinite with only one positive eigenvalue and a negative eigenvalue.

Since there exists an increasing function $f$ satisfying
$$
f(1)=-1, \ \ f(2)=0,
$$

It is not always true that $f(A)$ is positive semidefinite.